# Dynamically set user defined variable

Tags: java, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Is there any way to dynamically set the user defined variable within the jmx file during the startup of the test by using Java?

So far I am able to print the name by using this code:

```
 try {

            // JMeter Engine
            StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();

            // Initialize Properties, logging, locale, etc.
            JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("c:\\path\\jmeter.properties");
            JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("C:\\path\\apache-jmeter-5.0");
            JMeterUtils.initLocale();

            // Initialize JMeter SaveService
            SaveService.loadProperties();

            // Load existing .jmx Test Plan
            Path path = Paths.get("C:\\path\\whatever.jmx");
            HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(path.toFile());

            // Run JMeter Test
            jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);

            JMeterTreeModel treeModel = new JMeterTreeModel();
            JMeterTreeNode root = (JMeterTreeNode) treeModel.getRoot();
            treeModel.addSubTree(testPlanTree, root);

            SearchByClass<TestPlan> testPlan = new SearchByClass<>(TestPlan.class);
            testPlanTree.traverse(testPlan);
            Collection<TestPlan> testPlans = testPlan.getSearchResults();
            for (TestPlan testPlan1 : testPlans) {
                System.out.println(testPlan1.getName());

                JMeterProperty udvProperty = testPlan1.getUserDefinedVariablesAsProperty();

                Arguments arg = (Arguments) udvProperty.getObjectValue();

                CollectionProperty arguments = arg.getArguments();

                arguments.forEach(c -> {

                    System.out.println(c);

                });

            }

            // jmeter.run();

        }
        catch (IOException | IllegalUserActionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I am almost there! But just need some suggestions of whether this is the correct direction to go? Or there is another better approach?

**Update:**
I am able to set the variable by modify above code to:

```
try {

            // JMeter Engine
            StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();

            // Initialize Properties, logging, locale, etc.
            JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("c:\\path\\jmeter.properties");
            JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("C:\\path\\apache-jmeter-5.0");
            JMeterUtils.initLocale();

            // Initialize JMeter SaveService
            SaveService.loadProperties();

            // Load existing .jmx Test Plan
            Path path = Paths.get("C:\\path\\whatever.jmx");
            HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(path.toFile());

            // Run JMeter Test
            jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);

            JMeterTreeModel treeModel = new JMeterTreeModel();
            JMeterTreeNode root = (JMeterTreeNode) treeModel.getRoot();
            treeModel.addSubTree(testPlanTree, root);

            SearchByClass<TestPlan> testPlan = new SearchByClass<>(TestPlan.class);
            testPlanTree.traverse(testPlan);
            Collection<TestPlan> testPlans = testPlan.getSearchResults();
            for (TestPlan testPlan1 : testPlans) {
                System.out.println(testPlan1.getName());

                JMeterProperty udvProperty = testPlan1.getUserDefinedVariablesAsProperty();

                Arguments arg = (Arguments) udvProperty.getObjectValue();

                CollectionProperty arguments = arg.getArguments();

                arguments.forEach(c -> {

                Argument j = (Argument) c.getObjectValue();
                System.out.println("-----j--- " + j.getName());
                j.setValue("whatever value");

                System.out.println(j);

                });

            }

            // jmeter.run();

        }
        catch (IOException | IllegalUserActionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User Defined Variables test element is represented by [org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/config/Arguments.html) class so it makes sense to directly look up for Arguments as it will be more convenient, fast and readable.

There is [addArgument()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/config/Arguments.html#addArgument-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) function which can be used for adding an User Defined Variable

For example this code will read the test plan from defined location, add a User Defined Variable `foo` with the value of `bar` and save the Test Plan back

```
// JMeter Engine
StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();

// Initialize Properties, logging, locale, etc.
JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("c:\\path\\jmeter.properties");
JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("C:\\path\\apache-jmeter-5.0");
JMeterUtils.initLocale();

// Initialize JMeter SaveService
SaveService.loadProperties();

// Load existing .jmx Test Plan
Path path = Paths.get("C:\\path\\whatever.jmx");
HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(path.toFile());

SearchByClass<Arguments> udvSearch = new SearchByClass<>(Arguments.class);
testPlanTree.traverse(udvSearch);
Collection<Arguments> udvs = udvSearch.getSearchResults();

Arguments userDefinedVariables = udvs.stream().findAny().get();

System.out.println("Current values:");

userDefinedVariables.getArgumentsAsMap().forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println("Name : " + k + " Value : " + v));

userDefinedVariables.addArgument("foo", "bar");

SaveService.saveTree(testPlanTree, new FileOutputStream("C:\\path\\whatever.jmx"));
```

Check out [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) for more information regarding different ways of creating a JMeter test plan (including running an existing test and creating a brand new one using [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html))

Comment: The Five Ways link supplied shows among the others the CLI way which is great.

Answer (score 0):

After careful research, I came up with this code snippet. I have tested this on JMeter versions 5.3 and above and it works for me. It looks similar to the other answers, but I have carefully explained what's happening in each line. Hope this helps.

```
// Initialize Properties, logging, locale, etc.
JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("apache-jmeter-5.3/bin/jmeter.properties");
JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("apache-jmeter-5.3"); // Have the apache JMeter extracted in the same folder
JMeterUtils.initLocale();

try {
    // Initialize JMeter SaveService
    SaveService.loadProperties();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle the error
}

// add user defined variables
HashMap<String, String> userArguments = new HashMap<>();
userArguments.put("variable1", "value1");
userArguments.put("variable2", "value2");
userArguments.put("variable3", "value3");

String jmxFilePath = "jmeterscript.jmx";
File jmxFile = new File(jmxFilePath);

// get the jmeter to run by configuring it
StandardJMeterEngine jMeterEngine = configureJmeterEngine(jmxFile, userArguments);

// starting to invoke the JMeter Script
jMeterEngine.run();
jMeterEngine.reset();
jMeterEngine.exit();

/**
 * This method returns a configured StandardJMeterEngine based on a arguments configured in
 * a JMX file and arguments defined by user through metadata
 *
 * @param jmxFileName JMX file path
 * @param arguments   User defined arguments
 * @return Configured StandardJMeterEngine
 */
private StandardJMeterEngine configureJmeterEngine(File jmxFileName, HashMap<String, String> arguments) {
    StandardJMeterEngine standardJMeterEngine = new StandardJMeterEngine();
    try {
        // Get test plan tree
        HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(jmxFileName);
        // Get all user defined arguments in JMX file
        SearchByClass<Arguments> udvSearch = new SearchByClass<>(Arguments.class);
        testPlanTree.traverse(udvSearch);
        Collection<Arguments> udvs = udvSearch.getSearchResults();
        Arguments args = udvs.stream().findAny().orElseGet(Arguments::new);
        // Add user defined arguments in metadata
        arguments.keySet().forEach(key -> args.addArgument(key, arguments.get(key)));
        // Configure JMeter engine
        standardJMeterEngine.configure(testPlanTree);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error in configuring a Jmeter Probe", e);
    }
    return standardJMeterEngine;
}
```